How to prevent factorization of polynomials in output
The output of my program is a matrix with polynomial entries. Most often Mathematica rearranges the polynomials with some partial or full factorization, as in $p^2q+q^2(p+q)$ or $p(p+q)$. I would like the traditional arrangement of ascending degree of one variable and descending degree of the other one (the polynomials are homogeneous) as in $p^2q+pq^2+q^3$. How can I force Mathematica to do such a display and how do I control which variable will be ascending/first etc?

You can try Expand? I just did Expand[p^2*q+q^2*(p+q)] and got what you wanted which is p^2 q + p q^2 + q^3

@Nasser yes, MatrixForm[Expand[M]] works but Expand[MatrixForm[M]] does not.

Expand[MatrixForm[M]] does not. Yes ofcourse. MatrixForm is display wrapper. It prevents evaluation. This is by design in Mathematica.
